# JAVA: I have to write a program to read "sentences" from a file and and then count the number of words and vowels per sentence

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am working on a project where I wanted to create a file(ask user to input 'sentences'), read from it(read those sentences) and then find the number of words and vowels in EACH sentence.
Then I had planned to display them is this manner:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**(ignore the dots, they are just there to show spaces)

Sentence.........       Number of Words......       Number of vowels

sentence 1.......x................................y

**CURRENT OUTPUT**
I am getting an output where the number of vowels and words is the sum of the previous and current number of vowels and words
example: if the 1st sentence had 2 vowels and 2 words and even the second sentence would have the same number of vowels and words then the output would be:
Sentence.........       Number of Words......       Number of vowels

sentence 1.......2................................2

sentence 2.......4................................4

So my question is that:
For some reason i am not able to print in the way I want to (i.e-get number of vowels and words for **EACH** sentence), could you please help me rectify my program?

here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
class asgn5_3
{
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main (String args[])throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of sentences to be inputted");
        int sencounter=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String sentence="";

        int j = 0;//counter
        try//writing sentences to file
        {
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("c:\\users\\abc\\desktop\\TEXT.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);            
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            for (j=1;j<=sencounter;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter your sentence:");
                sentence=br.readLine();
                pw.println(sentence);

            }    
            pw.close();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:\\users\\abc\\desktop\\TEXT.txt");//reading from a file
        BufferedReader sb = new BufferedReader (fr);
        String text;
        int i =0;//counter
        int numberofwords=0;
        int vowels=0;
        char ch;
        System.out.print("Sentence");
        System.out.print("          Number of words");
        System.out.println("          Number of vowels");

        while((text=sb.readLine())!=null)//counting words
        {
            StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(text);
            numberofwords=numberofwords+words.countTokens();

            for (i=0;i<sentence.length();i++)//counting vowels
            {
                ch=sentence.charAt(i);
                if (ch=='a'||ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
                {
                    vowels++;
                }

            }
            System.out.print(sentence);
            System.out.print("          "+numberofwords);
            System.out.println("                        "+vowels);

        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: I am unable to print in the way i want, and i cant figure out what the problem is in my program

Comment: So, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output? Be precise. Use code formatting to display examples of both outputs.

Comment: Is there any reason, why you are writing the sentences to a file and then are reading them again?

Comment: How about: `System.out.println(sentence+" "+numberofwords+" "+vowels);` ?

Comment: i am supposed to make a program where the user enters sentences into a file and then i am supposed to output like i mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- You are using last user entered sentence while you should use text that you read from file like below:

  ```
    StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(text);
    numberofwords=numberofwords+words.countTokens();

    for (i=0;i<text.length();i++)
    {
        ch=text.charAt(i);
        if (ch=='a'||ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
        {
            vowels++;
        }

    }
    System.out.print(text);
  ```
- You keep on reusing the count and hence you get cumulative sum in order to avoid this reset your counters when read every line from file as below:

  vowels = 0;
  numberofwords = 0;

So in all your code should be:

```
  while((text=sb.readLine())!=null)//counting words
  {
      vowels = 0;
      numberofwords = 0;
      StringTokenizer words = new StringTokenizer(text);
      numberofwords=numberofwords+words.countTokens();

      for (i=0;i<text.length();i++)
      {
          ch=text.charAt(i);
          if (ch=='a'||ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
          {
              vowels++;
          }

      }
      System.out.print(text);
      System.out.print("          "+numberofwords);
      System.out.println("                        "+vowels);

  }
```